# doing a do loop within macro sas

Tags: macros, sas

I have the following code:

```
%macro initial (first=, second=, third=, fourth=, final=); 
   data &first;
     set wtnodup.&first;
         DATE1 = INPUT(PUT(Date,8.),YYMMDD8.);
         format DATE1 monyy7.;
 RUN;

proc freq data=&first order= freq;                                                                                                                              
   tables date1*jobboardid / list out=&second (drop = percent rename=   
                                              (Count=CountNew));
 run;

 data &third;
  set &second (firstobs=2);
    if countnew le 49 then delete; 
 run;
proc sort data = &third;
   by jobboardid Date1;    
run;
data &fourth (keep = countnew oldcountnew Date1 rate from till jobboardid 
                                                                    rate);
    set &third;
        by jobboardid Date1;
        format From Till monyy7.;
        from = lag12(Date1);
        oldcountnew = lag12(countnew);

        if lag12(jobboardid) EQ jobboardid and
        INTCK('month', from, Date1) EQ 12 then do;
        till = Date1;
        rate =  ((countnew/oldcountnew)-1)*100;
       output;
    end;
run;
proc sort data = &fourth;
   by Date1 rate;
proc means data=&fourth noprint;
   by Date1;
output out=Result.&final median(rate)=medianRate;
run; 

%mend initial;
%initial (first = Alabama, second = AlabamaOne, third =AlabamaTwo, 
          fourth = AlabamaThree, final=AL_10);
%initial (first = Alaska, second = AlaskaOne, third =AlaskaTwo, 
          fourth = AlaskaThree, final=AK_10);
%initial (first = Arizona, second = ArizonaOne, third =ArizonaTwo, 
          fourth = ArizonaThree, final=AZ);
%initial (first = Arkansas, second = ArkansasOne, third =ArkansasTwo, 
          fourth= ArkansasThree, final=AR_10);
```

What I am trying to do is that in the part that puts the condition:

```
if countnew < 10 then delete;
```

I want to create a sort of do-loop that would delete the data when countnew is <10,20,30....until 70, and creates a separate data-set for each of of the iteration of when countnew is <10, 20, etc.

So I would have a final data-set for of the different iteration of when countnew

What is the best way about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Why not do-looping, ten by ten, and adding the iteration extension to the dataset name like this?

```
** Sample dataset;
data try;
do i=1 to 1000;
value=1+ranuni(12345)*100;
output;
end;
drop i;
run;


** Macro iterator:

%macro iter(ds=);

%do i=10 %to 70 %by 10;

    data &ds._&i;
    set &ds;
    if value le &i then delete;
    run;

%end;

%mend;

%iter (ds=try)
```

you will have 7 dataset named try_10--try_70  where try will be replaced with the dataset name.

Comment: So I would add this loop within my bigger loop? I am a little confused.

Comment: Have you understood the meaning of that macro loop with a datastep named and filtered based on the value of the iterator i ?
If so, simply add that loop (without macro specification and macro call) inside your loop (from %do to %end) at the step where you want to do this operation. I think that &ds for me, is &second for you.